# Should we merge [stream-analytics] into [azure-stream-analytics]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[azure-stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-stream-analytics) has 840 questions and a stub of a tag wiki.

[stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-analytics) has 84 questions and no tag wiki.

Of the 84 questions in [stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-analytics), [only 4 aren't explicitly about Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstream-analytics%5D+is%3Aquestion+-azure+-%5Bazure%5D+-%5Bazure-stream-analytics%5D+-%5Bazure-iot-hub%5D). None of the 4 remaining questions are particularly high-quality.

The 4 non-Azure questions in [stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-analytics) have different interpretations of what "stream-analytics" means, but generally are about logging and debugging data which is supplied via a stream.

Because I don't do too much work on streaming myself, I'm not sure if the [stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-analytics) tag could be useful outside of Azure.

Should we make [stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-analytics) a synonym of [azure-stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-stream-analytics)?

Should we instead re-tag questions in [stream-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream-analytics) where they're specifically related to Azure?

Comment: I don't know much about Azure but I'd rather split azure-stream-analytics into azure and stream-analytics just like python-textprocessing. The only reason azure-stream-analytics should exist is if stream-analytics in Azure is special. That's why we have a c-string tag and no c++-string tag or python-string tag. I know `\0` about Auzure, so I won't give my opinion.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam [There are 852](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-stream-analytics+or+stream-analytics) questions tagged [tag:stream-analytics] or [tag:azure-stream-analytics]. 4 of which are not about Azure.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam  - terrible idea. Questions tagged `azure-stream-analytics` will be about that specific product - not about general concept of doing analytics on streams.

Comment: @MartinSmith Okay then, I have no idea about the details of Azure. I told it.

Comment: @Joundill You can't just claim that all `stream-analytics` are `azure-stream-analytics`. There can be rival service. What happens to those 4 questions though?

Comment: @ShambhavGautam Do you know of a rival service with the exact same name? Also, if AWS had its own product called "AWS Stream Analytics", I'm confident it'd be so different to [azure-stream-analytics] that it wouldn't make sense to have a single tag for both products.

Comment: I bet we could just re-tag the 80 that are about Azure, remove the tag from the remaining four, and wait to see if it gets recreated.

Comment: @ShambhavGautam Nobody gets to claim stream-analytics. That's the preferred way when to namespaces collide. That would totally avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @TylerH I think you're probably right.

Comment: *"The [confluence](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/confluence#Noun) [stream-analytics] and [azure-stream-analytics]"*. (Or variations.)